# Writing a unit test case

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have started using unit test in some of my projects and I have a small issue, I need to test one method and I have run out of ideas as an example: I have this

```
    public class Clients
    {
      Public Assignment AssignClient(int? clientRef, int? productRef)
       //Assignment is an enum that has success,Failure,etc...
        {
         If(!checkClientAge(int clientRef)) Return Assignment.Tooyoung;
          If(!checkClientAvailability(int clientRef)) Return Assignment.NotAvailable;
         If(! checkProductavailability(int productRef)) Return Assignment.ProductNotAvailable;
        }
     }
```

I done a mock on the client class and the `AssignClient`, but I am not sure what to do with three boolean methods, not sure if you have any idea on how I can mock these?

Comment: why internal methods bother you when you already mocked AssignClient() method?

Comment: There is no way to tell unless you show the code for each.

Comment: @Dima Well that was one thought as someone suggested that I shouldn't send anything to the db, but also I am getting an error on sqlconnection not initialised when I just do a mock on AssignClient

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing the `Clients` class then you don't mock it, you need a real instance. Instead you mock out the other classes it uses so that you can return known and predictable results from them and eliminate complications like database access, UI interaction, etc.

The `AssignClient` method is not a good candidate for unit testing unless the three calls to private methods set externally visible flags or properties - if they don't then there is nothing to measure or observe, you cannot tell if the test succeeded or failed.

Comment: Clients class has so many method and assignclient is one of them I was interested in writing a test because this one is used in so many other instance and has changed over the time, I didin't put the whole code, but for instance the checkClientAge(int clientRef)is like this: if(!checkClientAge(int clientRef)) return Assignment.TooYoung; etc.....

Comment: @JackM That is an excellent reason for testing that class and/or method. The `Assignment` enum is what you should be checking - pass in values that you know should fail, and check the return result is what you expect. Then pass in correct values and check the result. Typically you would test each externally accessible method that actually does something (not everything will be worth testing).

Comment: I don't clearly get what you are saying can do with an example please or reference of where this was done.

Comment: and Others, I  have actually resolved this and the way I did it was to mock one method at a time and checking the result, without have to touch the database, and then checking the redult.